# Sublime text: how to customize syntax highlighting?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I use *Smarty* to generate html templates. I currently use html highlighting, which is mostly fine, except it doesn't highlight smarty tags, ex `{foreach}`
I tried installing the Smarty package, but that doesn't look very good.

So basically I need to be able to add highlighting of anything within curly brackets to standard HTML coloring. **How can this be done?**

Comment: It's kind of a vague question, so I can only vaguely say to try brackethighlighter2.

Answer (score 26):

## Background

@MattDMo is right that a `.tmTheme` file is the principal file which controls the highlighting. It is an XML file with a series of Regular Expressions and tags that denote which RegEx matches which type of syntactic element.

You can search on GitHub and find many people who have already created Sublime Text packages which contain `.tmTheme` files. Note that you can directly use a package created for TextMate, as Sublime Text uses the same conventions. (This is true at least insofar as `.tmTheme` and `.tmPreferences` files go.)

For example, I was able to directly take a syntax highlighting package for the ChucK language, originally made for TextMate, and use it SublimeText2. The `.tmTheme` worked immediately by copying the file used with TextMate. I just removed additional junk files and then made a few changes to the `.tmTheme`, as well as added support for the Package Manager.

See that project here: https://github.com/nathanleiby/ChucK.tmbundle.

## How to install new syntaxes

*Package Control*

Ideally, the syntax you already want is included available for download in the Sublime Text Package Control. Search in Package Control and install directly. (If you don't have Package Control yet, you must get it: https://github.com/wbond/package_control_channel/)

*Manually*

If you download a `.tmTheme` file or `.tmBundle` directly, you'll want to copy it to the appropriate packages folder in ST. Note that there is a `/Packages` folder and a `/Packages/User` folder. The ST2 documentation suggests copying to the latter, as it is guaranteed to be preserved even if other packages in the main folder are erased / modified during an update.

On OSX, that directory is: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/`

(Note: You may prefer to `git clone` the package into this folder, so that you can easily update it.)

## How to Create Your Own

If you want to dig in and customize the syntax highlighting, here are few places to get started.

- Brush up on your Regular Expressions.
- [Sublime Text documentation for syntax definitions](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html)
- `<ctrl> + <shift> + p`. Whenever you're looking at a file, select any word and press this key combination, then look in the footer bar. You should see a series of syntax descriptions. For example: I just highlighted a word in the SQL file I'm looking at and the response was: `source.sql string.other.quoted.backtick.sql`.
- You'll probably prefer to parse your syntax using JavaScript / JSON, rather than XML. Use [PackageDev](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev). You can get this via Package Control. It has commands that allow you to go back and forth between .json (JSON) and .tmTheme (XML) files.
- A [related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010032/how-to-add-syntax-highlighting-to-sublime-text-2).

## Caveat

This may be obvious, but the usefulness of syntax highlighting is related to which Color Scheme you have chosen in Sublime Text. (Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Color Scheme -> ...)

I haven't yet had a chance explore/verify this in detail, but it seems that some color schemes may distinguish between more/less types of of syntax elements.

I highly recommend the "Monokai" color scheme (particularly, the "Monokai Soda" variant) for this reason -- it seems to "bring out the colors".

Comment: If you want a nicely contrasting theme with lots of (customizable) scopes, check out my [Neon.tmTheme](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon.tmTheme). It's bright-on-black, and while I use it primarily for Python, it looks good with many other languages, including HTML/CSS/JavaScript. And yes, you are correct in stating that some color schemes don't have as many scopes as others. I've collated a bunch of scopes from other schemes for my theme, so hopefully there'll be something there for you to use. However, it all depends on how fine-grained the .tmLanguage file is.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo - I'll give it a shot! Looks very simple and clean. And good to know my observation was on-track, that some color schemes distinguish among more/less syntactic scopes.

Comment: The above link for "Sublime Text documentation for syntax definitions" seems invalid. This may be a copy/alternative: https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html

Comment: Thanks @awatts! I've updated to use that link instead.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to modify your `.tmTheme` to add custom highlighting for the scopes defined by setting your syntax to Smarty. There should be a `Smarty.tmlanguage` file in the `Packages/Smarty/Syntaxes` directory. It's XML, so it can be a little tough for casual reading, but if you understand regexes and the scopes are named intelligently, you should be able to figure out how to modify your theme.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple

1. With Sublime Text 2 default installation
2. Open file "Packages\HTML\HTML.tmLanguage", if you search for string **`<!--`** you will notice that (currently) there is two references to "Smarty" commented. Un-comment these.
3. In your `Smarty.tmLanguage` file search for the string **`scopeName`**. That's a key actually and the associated string should be something like **`text.html.smarty`**.
4. Copy that string into `HTML.tmLanguage` in place of **`source.smarty`** (the string for the key `include` at the end of the last block you just un-commented)

That's it. Enjoy

Comment: It'd be great if you could explain where "Packages\HTML\HTML.tmLanguage" is or how to open in Sublime Text. I wouldn't know this information off the top of my head.

Comment: In sublimetext's menu there is a link called ```browse packages```. This will open the destination folder of your packages (with finder or Explorer for example).